# Layout Doesn't Match in Real Device

Tags: java, android, layout

When I designed my App UI , it looks good on the emulator, but when I run the app on a real device (which has a smaller screen), it looks so bad with some widgets stacked over each other, why? And what the solution?

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="musabnasr.com.weeklyaccomplished.MainActivity"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1"
>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="195dp"
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/userlogin"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/usernamefield"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.EditText"
    android:hint="user name:"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26sp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />

<EditText
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.EditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/passwordfield"
    android:hint="password :"
    android:layout_below="@+id/usernamefield"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="91sp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Log in or Sign Up"
    android:id="@+id/login_signup"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="150sp"/>
```

Comment: It is because you are using so much `Margin` to `Widget` also you have to   set your `Widget` accroding you give in `LinearLayout` is `WeightSum = 1`  then It's work also for small device.

Comment: thanks , i will give it a shot